# Show type string on a Django webpage instead of bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to get the contents of an XML file stored in an S3 bucket to show as text in the browser. However, it just displays as numbers (bytes) rather than a legible string.

**My code (views.py):**

```
def file_content(request):
    file_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", "eu-west-1")
    s3_client.download_fileobj("mybucket", "myfolder/example.xml", file_buffer)
    file_content = file_buffer.getvalue()
    return HttpResponse(file_content)
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried changing this line:

```
file_content = file_buffer.getvalue()
```

To:

```
file_content = file_buffer.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
```

Or:

```
file_content = str(file_buffer.getvalue())
```

But it is still displaying as numbers/ bytes in the browser. The file content displays correctly as a string when using print() or if I check type(file_content) in the console but this is not happening in the browser.

I'm not sure whats going wrong, if somebody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, I fixed this by adding a content_type to the HttpResponse so my function now looks like this:

```
def file_content(request):
    file_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", "eu-west-1")
    s3_client.download_fileobj("mybucket", "myfolder/example.xml", file_buffer)
    file_content = file_buffer.getvalue().decode('UTF-8')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/plain")
    response.write(file_content)
    return response
```